# Counting the occurences a particular item in a column

Tags: python, pandas, frequency

```
ctr = df['gender'].value_counts()

ctr

**Output:**

female       102

male          83

nonbinary      5

trans          2

Name: gender, dtype: int64
```

This is the output I got and I understand that this is how the output should look like. But I'm interested to know the frequency of a particular item under the 'gender' column, in this case for example; female or male, and want to store each of those frequencies to two separate variables. I'm relatively a newbie in this field. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way to do this will be to use value_counts().

As you already know, `df['gender'].value_counts()` will give you the distribution. However, you can also specify which one you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'gender':['male','female','trans','nonbinary',
                             'male','female','male','female',
                             'male','female','male','female',
                             'male','female','female','trans','nonbinary',
                             'male','male','male','trans',
                             'male','male','female','female',
                             'male','male','nonbinary','trans','male']})
#print (df)
m = df['gender'].value_counts().male
f = df['gender'].value_counts().female
t = df['gender'].value_counts().trans
b = df['gender'].value_counts().nonbinary

print (df['gender'].value_counts())
print ('male      :', m)
print ('female    :', f)
print ('trans     :', t)
print ('nonbinary :', b)
```

The output of this will be:

`values_counts()` will give you an output as:

```
male         14
female        9
trans         4
nonbinary     3
Name: gender, dtype: int64
```

However, specific prints will give you output as:

```
male      : 14
female    : 9
trans     : 4
nonbinary : 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.DataFrame({"a":["a","a","b"]}).a.value_counts(normalize=True)
```

All you have to do is add normalize.
I am pretty sure the question is a duplicate but I cant find it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this as a solution to what I was looking for....

```
fe =len(df[df['gender']=='female'])

fe
```

OUTPUT :102

Comment: use `value_counts()` instead